# Using a slice instead of list when working with large data volumes in Go

Tags: go, linked-list, slice

I have a question on the utility of slices in Go. I have just seen [Why are lists used infrequently in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326109/why-are-lists-used-infrequently-in-go) and [Why use arrays instead of slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694652/why-use-arrays-instead-of-slices) but had some question which I did not see answered there.

In my application:

- I read a CSV file containing approx 10 million records, with 23 columns per record.
- For each record, I create a struct and put it into a linked list.
- Once all records have been read, the rest of the application logic works with this linked list (the processing logic itself is not relevant for this question).

The reason I prefer a list and not a slice is due to the large amount of contiguous memory an array/slice would need. Also, since I don't know the size of the exact number of records in the file upfront, I can't specify the array size upfront (I know Go can dynamically re-dimension the slice/array as needed, but this seems terribly inefficient for such a large set of data).

Every Go tutorial or article I read seems to suggest that I should use slices and not lists (as a slice can do everything a list can, but do it better somehow). However, I don't see how or why a slice would be more helpful for what I need? Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: I see that someone has down-voted the question. Could you at least please explain why you're doing so? I really don't get why allocating (and re-dimmming) a large contiguous block of memory is a better idea than using several smaller non-contiguous blocks. Thanks.

Comment: Slices and linked listed are different things with different characteristics and if your solution works "better" (for your definition of better) with linked lists, just do so. I do not see a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... approx 10 million records, with 23 columns per record ... The reason I prefer a list and not a slice is due to the large amount of contiguous memory an array/slice would need.

This contiguous memory is its own benefit as well as its own drawback.  Let's consider both parts.

(Note that it is also possible to use a hybrid approach: a list of chunks.  This seems unlikely to be very worthwhile here though.)

> Also, since I don't know the size of the exact number of records in the file upfront, I can't specify the array size upfront (I know Go can dynamically re-dimension the slice/array as needed, but this seems terribly inefficient for such a large set of data).

Clearly, if there are *n* records, and you allocate and fill in each one once (using a list), this is O(*n*).

If you use a slice, and allocate a single extra slice entry every time, you start with none, grow it to size 1, then copy the 1 to a new array of size 2 and fill in item #2, grow it to size 3 and fill in item #3, and so on.  The first of the *n* entities is copied *n* times, the second is copied *n*-1 times, and so on, for *n*(*n*+1)/2 = O(n<sup>2</sup>) copies.  But if you use a multiplicative expansion technique—which Go's `append` implementation does—this drops to O(log *n*) copies.  Each one does copy more bytes though.  It ends up being O(*n*), amortized (see [Why do dynamic arrays have to geometrically increase their capacity to gain O(1) amortized push_back time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64734694/1256452)).

The space used with the slice is obviously O(*n*).  The space used for the linked list approach is O(*n*) as well (though the records now require at least one forward pointer so you need some extra space per record).

So in terms of the time needed to *construct* the data, and the space needed to *hold* the data, it's O(*n*) either way.  You end up with the same total memory requirement.  The main difference, at first glace anyway, is that the linked-list approach doesn't require *contiguous* memory.

So: What do we *lose* when using contiguous memory, and what do we *gain?*

#### What we lose

The thing we lose is obvious.  If we already have fragmented memory regions, we might not be *able* to get a contiguous block of the right size.  That is, given:

```
used: 1 MB (starting at base, ending at base+1M)
free: 1 MB (starting at +1M, ending at +2M)
used: 1 MB (etc)
free: 1 MB
used: 1 MB
free: 1 MB
```

we have a total of 6 MB, 3 used and 3 free.  We can allocate 3 1 MB blocks, but we can't allocate one 3 MB block unless we can somehow compact the three "used" regions.

Since Go programs tend to run in virtual memory on large-memory-space machines (virtual sizes of 64 GB or more), this tends not to be a big problem.  Of course everyone's situation differs, so if you really *are* VM-constrained, that's a real concern.  (Other languages have compacting GC to deal with this, and a future Go implementation could at least in theory use a compacting GC.)

#### What we gain

The first gain is also obvious: we don't need pointers in each record.  This saves some space—the exact amount depends on the size of the pointers, whether we're using singly linked lists, and so on.  Let's just assume 2 8 byte pointers, or 16 bytes per record.  Multiply by 10 million records and we're looking pretty good here: we've saved 160 MBytes.  (Go's `container/list` implementation uses a doubly linked list, and on a 64 bit machine, this is the size of the per-element threading needed.)

We gain something less obvious at first, though, and it's *huge*.  Because Go is a garbage-collected language, **every pointer is something the GC must examine at various times.**  The slice approach has *zero extra pointers* per record; the linked-list approach has *two*.  That means that the GC system can avoid examining the nonexistent 20 million pointers (in the 10 million records).

#### Conclusion

There *are* times to use `container/list`.  If your algorithm really calls for a list and is significantly clearer that way, do it that way, unless and until it proves to be a problem in practice.  Or, if you have items that can be on some collection of lists—items that are actually shared, but some of them are on the X list and some are on the Y list and some are on both—this calls for a list-style container.  But if there's an easy way to express something as either a list *or* a slice, go for the slice version first.  Because slices are built into Go, you also get the type safety / clarity mentioned in the first link ([Why are lists used infrequently in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21326109/1256452)).

Comment: Thanks @torek. The GC overhead is indeed something I was overlooking and is certainly one of the cons of using a double linked list.